# Word VBA - Apply multiple styles without overwriting using Range.Find

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use various subs in my documents to apply styles to certain formatted text, but I keep overwriting one style with another, even though my intention is to apply character level styles and paragraph level styles respectively.

**Question 1:** Can I make the below code work so that it would first apply the "Mention" Style to individual words that match the Find criteria, then apply a "Body Text" to the paragraphs without overwriting the mention style?

**Question 2:** I keep reading that `Selection.Find` should be avoided in most cases in favour of `Range.Find`. Is it possible to modify the below code to use `Range.Find`? Any insights on why this is generally better is also appreciated for my own educational purposes also appreciated!

Code:

```
Sub FormatText()
    
    'Apply style to "Mention" style to words matching the RGB color
    Selection.HomeKey Word.WdUnits.wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.TextColor = RGB(14, 86, 140)
        .Format = TRUE
        .Forward = TRUE
        .Text = ""
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
        Do While .Found
            .Parent.Expand Word.WdUnits.wdWord
            Selection.ClearFormatting
            Selection.Style = "Mention"
            Selection.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
            .Execute
        Loop
    End With
    
    'Apply "Body Text" Style to paragraphs with Font zieze 10 and no indentation
    Selection.HomeKey Word.WdUnits.wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Size = 10
        .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 0
        .ParagraphFormat.RightIndent = 0
        .Format = TRUE
        .Forward = TRUE
        .Text = ""
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
        Do While .Found
            .Parent.Expand Word.WdUnits.wdParagraph
            Selection.ClearFormatting
            Selection.Style = "Body Text"
            Selection.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
            .Execute
        Loop
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You should apply paragraph Styles *before* applying character Styles. This forum is replete with examples of VBA Find/Replace code using ranges rather than selections - a trivial bit of research would turn up lots of useful examples.

Comment: If I reverse the two find/replace code blocks above, so the paragraph style replace goes first, it overrides all of the formatting in that paragraph, so that the subsequent find/replace won't pick up the coloured text in the next run.

Comment: The only reason "it overrides all of the formatting in that paragraph" is because you have told it to, that's what `Selection.ClearFormatting` does. It isn't needed, so just delete it.